# I'm trying to make a game in python and this if statement isn't working

Tags: python

I'm trying to make a 60 seconds ripoff kind of game in python and when I try to substract in the if statement it just doesn't work

```
Seconds = 60
Weapon = input("Would you like to take the axe(-5 seconds) or the shotgun(-10 seconds) (can take both if ya want)  ")
if Weapon.lower().startswith("s"):
    Seconds - 10
    print("now you have a shotgun")
print(Seconds)
```

I there is of course more code but this just isn't working I hope there is a fix for it

Comment: The expression `Seconds - 10` calculates a value then throws it away. You probably want to to store the result somewhere, e.g. `Seconds = Seconds - 10` or more concisely `Seconds -= 10`

Comment: "Just doesn't work" tells people exactly nothing about the problem.  (The one thing we can guarantee about this code, and about any code, is that it does *exactly* what it's written to do.  So, in that sense, it most certainly *does* "work".  But we don't know what you are *expecting* it to do.)  Do you get an error message?  Do you observe an unexpected result?  Something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have forgotten the equals-sign in your *Seconds* assignment.

```py
Seconds -= 10
```

Comment: Thank you so much i have been trying this for over 2 months and resorted to stack overflow as a last resort, thank you